# Why do I have to send two consecutive HTTP Get requests to be authenticated?

Tags: delphi, http, basic-authentication, indy, indy10

This is a follow-up question to [a prior question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599238/indy-tidhttp-uri-with-login-password-not-working). I've come to learn that when using the HTTP username/password parameters in a request, there are 2 different `Get` requests expected to be sent to the server. The first attempt does not include username/password credentials, but if authentication fails, it then sends another identical request which does include these credentials.

While using Indy's `TIdHTTP` however, it only sends one request, which fails with `Unauthorized`. It takes a second identical consecutive request to actually be able to get a response as needed.

I'm wondering, is this by design, or is it a flaw in Indy?

Comment: Don't you just need to handle the [`OnAuthorization`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdHTTP_OnAuthorization.html) event ?

Comment: Look at IdHttpInstance.Request.UserName & Password properties

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo Way ahead of ya :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you:

1. have the `hoInProcessAuth` flag enabled in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property.
2. have either:

   a. an `OnAuthorization` event handler assigned that sets the `Authentication.UserName` and `Authentication.Password` parameters, and the `Handled` parameter to True.

   b. a non-blank string assigned to the `TIdHTTP.Request.Password` property.
3. any necessary `IdAuthentication...` unit(s) (such as `IdAuthenticationNTLM` or `IdAuthenticationSSPI`), or the `IdAllAuthentications` unit, specified in your `uses` clause.

If those conditions are not met, `TIdHTTP` will not attempt to handle HTTP-based authentication.

Comment: [sends a virtual beer to Remy] That just solved everything, and answers my prior question too :-)

Comment: Specifically the `hoInProcessAuth` part is what fixed it all

Answer (score 7):

This is because the *HTTP Negotiate* authentication method is used:

["NTLM and Negotiate (RFC-4559) is most commonly used on Microsoft IIS web servers. NTLM can be used exclusively, but modern servers typically use Negotiate to select which scheme will be used. The result is usually NTLM'](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/2011/06/how-http-authentication-works-and-why-load-testers-should-care/)

[Microsoft explains it e.g. here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995329.aspx) (see Figure 1)

If you [Google for http request negotiation www-authenticate](https://www.google.com/search?q=http+request+negotiation+www-authenticate) you'll find more info.

As an illustration, this is the HTTP that I see if SOAPUI makes an authenticated connection to Exchange web services:

```
1>  >> "POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
    >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
    >> "SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/ResolveNames"[\r][\n]"
    >> "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
    >> "Content-Length: 548[\r][\n]"
    >> "Host: webmail.ttbv.nl[\r][\n]"
    >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
    >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
    >> "[\r][\n]"
    >> "<soapenv:Envelope [\n]"
    [snip]
    >> "</soapenv:Envelope>[\n]"
    >> "[\n]"

1<  << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
    << "Cache-Control: private[\r][\n]"
    << "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5[\r][\n]"
    << "X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727[\r][\n]"
    << "Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=a29f10ca2a6d484ea276737e87d8e733; expires=Wed, 13-Nov-2013 10:47:33 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly[\r][\n]"
    << "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate[\r][\n]"
    << "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM[\r][\n]"
    << "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
    << "Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 10:47:33 GMT[\r][\n]"
    << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
    << "[\r][\n]"

2>  >> "POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
    >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
    >> "SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/ResolveNames"[\r][\n]"
    >> "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
    >> "Content-Length: 548[\r][\n]"
    >> "Host: webmail.ttbv.nl[\r][\n]"
    >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
    >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
    >> "Cookie: exchangecookie=a29f10ca2a6d484ea276737e87d8e733[\r][\n]"
    >> "Cookie2: $Version=1[\r][\n]"
    >> "Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAAB[snip]QgBWAA==[\r][\n]"
    >> "[\r][\n]"
    >> "<soapenv:Envelope [\n]"
    [snip]
    >> "</soapenv:Envelope>[\n]"
    >> "[\n]"

2<  << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
    << "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5[\r][\n]"
    << "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTU[snip]AACAAAAFAAAAA==[\r][\n]"
    << "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate[\r][\n]"
    << "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
    << "Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 10:47:33 GMT[\r][\n]"
    << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
    << "[\r][\n]"

3>  >> "POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
    >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
    >> "SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/ResolveNames"[\r][\n]"
    >> "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
    >> "Content-Length: 548[\r][\n]"
    >> "Host: webmail.ttbv.nl[\r][\n]"
    >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
    >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
    >> "Cookie: exchangecookie=a29f10ca2a6d484ea276737e87d8e733[\r][\n]"
    >> "Cookie2: $Version=1[\r][\n]"
    >> "Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNT[snip]AVABUADcANAA=[\r][\n]"
    >> "[\r][\n]"
    >> "<soapenv:Envelope [\n]"
    [snip]
    >> "</soapenv:Envelope>[\n]"
    >> "[\n]"

3<  << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
    << "Cache-Control: private[\r][\n]"
    << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
    << "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
    << "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5[\r][\n]"
    << "X-EwsPerformanceData: RpcC=2;RpcL=0;LdapC=1;LdapL=0;[\r][\n]"
    << "X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727[\r][\n]"
    << "Persistent-Auth: true[\r][\n]"
    << "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
    << "Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 10:47:33 GMT[\r][\n]"
    << "[\r][\n]"
    << "877[\r][\n]"
    << "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    [snip]
    << "</s:Envelope>"
    << "[\r][\n]"
    << "0[\r][\n]"
    << "[\r][\n]"
```

In the first received HTTP block the server tells me what protocols I can use.

So the second request is not, as you write *if authentication fails*, it is by design; hence no username and password have to be sent with the first request.

Comment: Yes, however, `TIdHTTP` is designed to handle such cases and automatically send subsequent authentication requires without requiring the user to do so manually.